# How can I Implement terminal scrolling?

Tags: c, ubuntu, scroll, kernel, qemu

I am currently in the midst of implementing features to a kernel. Terminal scrolling is a feature I would like to add, but not sure how. It can currently only hold 25 lines and overwrites data when any new lines are added.

This is the code I currently have:

```
void terminal_scroll(){
   for(int i = 0; i < VGA_HEIGHT; i++){
      for (int m = 0; m < VGA_WIDTH; m++){
         terminal_buffer[i * VGA_WIDTH + m] = terminal_buffer[(i + 1) * VGA_WIDTH + m];
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It will be easier to use a 2D buffer that holds more than 25 lines. Instead of physically moving the data, use it like a ring buffer. You will need variables that tell you the oldest line, how many lines are stored, and the current top line in the viewport.

Comment: Oh - I misread the question, thinking you want to be able to scroll the terminal history. But it is still more efficient to overwite one line, than shuffle the whole buffer.

Comment: Perhaps my arithmetic isn't up to it, but it looks to me as if you will try to scroll up the line below the bottom of the screen. At any rate, I suspect this kind of thing is easier and faster using `memmove()` or something, if your terminal buffer is organized in contiguous rows.